# Cannot find 'SectorMark' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

I'm trying create a Pie Charts in SwiftUI via SectorMark but I have a error "Cannot find 'SectorMark' in scope". So Swift detected this like a property or variable not like a method.

Please, help me find a solution

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct MacroData {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}

struct CircleIndicatorView: View {
    
    @State private var macros: [MacroData] = [
        .init(name: "Free money", value: 3800),
        .init(name: "Taxes", value: 800),
        .init(name: "Regular Payment", value: 3000)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(macros, id: \.name) { macro in
                SectorMark(angle: .value("Macros", macro.value)
                
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Name", macro.name))
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .chartXAxis(.hidden)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CircleIndicatorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleIndicatorView()
    }
}
```

I try to find solution myself, but...
I know, this a new method, but how I can added it in my project?
Thank you everyone for help me

Comment: Are you using the Xcode Beta?

Comment: No. It is importatnt?

Comment: The SectorMark documentation says that that specific API is in beta, so yeah, it won’t be available on previous versions of Xcode, and won’t be available for projects targeting iOS 16 or lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/sectormark

It is only available in Beta now.

> iOS 17.0+ Beta
> iPadOS 17.0+ Beta
> macOS 14.0+ Beta
> Mac Catalyst 17.0+ Beta
> tvOS 17.0+ Beta
> watchOS 10.0+ Beta
> visionOS 1.0+ Beta

You need a developer account and Xcode 15 from

https://developer.apple.com/